# My custom "newest unanswered in specific tags" URL sporadically not working?

Tags: discussion, bug

I use the following URL to select newest, unanswered questions with a set of tags.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?tagnames=xslt+or+xml+or+java+or+or+html+or+linux+or+perl+or+tomcat+or+mysql+or+database+or+xsl+or+xslt-2.0+&tab=newest
```

This has worked for 5 years, but over the past few days I've had it fail to return any results several times.  When I started composing this question it hadn't been working for about 15 minutes, but I just checked again and it is now working again.

I've seen this behavior 3 times in the last week.

Is this a bug, or possibly a load issue? I've noticed response times much longer than usual in the last week or so.

I am also seeing similar behavior when clicking on the unfiltered "newest" button

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest
```

The page is empty.

Also the "featured" tab shows 418 questions in the badge but the page itself is empty.

... a few seconds pass ...

In fact, the "featured" tab just disappeared when I reloaded the page, so I assume either the site is in the process of being updated or something's seriously broken.

... a few more seconds pass ...

Now the "featured" tab is back but my custom URL (at the top) is no longer working.

This is starting to feel like a game of Whack-a-mole!

Comment: I'm getting zero questions sometimes currently, pretty sure they're doing something behind the scenes.

Comment: Pff, now it's shy with me too.

Comment: Are you still seeing this behavior? I keep getting it in Firefox, not Chrome, esp. when I use the back button to return to the questions list.

Comment: Not in quite a while, no.  I'm still using Firefox (35.0.1)